# How do I return an array that has 'cats' first and 'water' in between 'cats' and 'dogs'?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I have so far:

```
var separate = [cats, water, dogs];
separate.sort(function(cats, water, dogs) {return cats-water-dogs});
```

Problem:

Dogs don't get along with cats, and cats don't get along with dogs.

What they both have in common is that they don't get along with water (baths).

Given an array of 'dogs', 'cats', and 'water', write a function called `separate`, which returns a new array so that the dogs are separated from the cats by water. Make sure that cats always come first in the array.

You can assume that the array will always at least three elements, and that there'll always be at least one dog, one cat, and one water to work with.

```
Examples:

separate(['dog','cat','water']) // ['cat','water','dog']

separate(['dog','cat','water','cat']) // ['cat', 'cat', 'water', 'dog'])

separate(['cat','cat','water','dog','water','cat','water','dog']) 
  // ['cat','cat','cat','water','water','water','dog','dog']

separate(
   ['cat','cat','cat','cat','cat',
    'cat','cat','cat','cat','cat','cat',
    'cat','cat','cat','cat','cat','cat','cat',
    'dog','water','water','water','water','water',
    'water','water','water','water','water','water',
    'water','water','water'
]) 

 // ['cat','cat','cat','cat','cat',
    'cat','cat','cat','cat','cat','cat',
    'cat','cat','cat','cat','cat','cat','cat',
    'water','water','water','water','water',
    'water','water','water','water','water','water',
    'water','water','water', 'dog']
```

Comment: The `.sort` callback only accepts two parameters, not 3

Comment: Hi Kevin, I'd recommend reading up on Array.sort and show more of an attempt to code an answer if you want assistance: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

You should use the function `sort` and move the dog values to the last position as follow:

- When `a === 'dog'` return `1` because dog should be at the end.
- When `b === 'dog'` return `-1` because the value of `a` should be before `b`.

```js
let arr = ['cat','cat','cat','cat','cat',
    'cat','cat','cat','cat','cat','cat',
    'cat','cat','cat','cat','cat','cat','cat',
    'dog','water','water','water','water','water',
    'water','water','water','water','water','water',
    'water','water','water'];
let result = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a === 'dog') return 1;
  if (b === 'dog') return -1;
  else return a.localeCompare(b); // cat always at the beginning.
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

HEre we use sort with a custom sort algorithm that understands the difference between dogs, cats and water

```js
// Use this to assign a value 0,1,2 to split them
const weight = (a) => (a === 'dog') ? 0 : (a === 'water') ? 1 : 2;

// our sort will use the weight
const sortItem = (a,b) => weight(a) - weight(b);

const separate = (arr) => arr.sort(sortItem);

console.log(separate(['dog','cat','water'])); // ['cat','water','dog']

console.log(separate(['dog','cat','water','cat'])); // ['cat', 'cat', 'water', 'dog'])

console.log(separate(['cat','cat','water','dog','water','cat','water','dog']));
```

Answer (score 0):

up

```js
let arr = ['cat','cat','cat','cat','cat',
    'cat','cat','cat','cat','cat','cat',
    'cat','cat','cat','cat','cat','cat','cat',
    'dog','water','water','water','water','water',
    'water','water','water','water','water','water',
    'water','water','water'];
let result = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a === 'dog') return 1;
  if (b === 'dog') return -1;
  else return a.localeCompare(b); // cat always at the beginning.
});

console.log(result);
```

```js
// Use this to assign a value 0,1,2 to split them
const weight = (a) => (a === 'dog') ? 0 : (a === 'water') ? 1 : 2;

// our sort will use the weight
const sortItem = (a,b) => weight(a) - weight(b);

const separate = (arr) => arr.sort(sortItem);

console.log(separate(['dog','cat','water'])); // ['cat','water','dog']

console.log(separate(['dog','cat','water','cat'])); // ['cat', 'cat', 'water', 'dog'])

console.log(separate(['cat','cat','water','dog','water','cat','water','dog']));
```